# Optimized Stock Trading Script

Tags: python, r

I have a CSV file with dates and data points, which are just -1, 0, and 1.  A -1 means a stock closed the day lower than it opened (money is lost), a 0 means there was no change in the price, and 1 means the stock closed the day higher than it opened.  How can I write a script, in R or Python, to find the optimal trading pattern?  If the stock is going up I want to buy it, if it is going down, I want to sell it, and if there is no change in price then do nothing.

I'm guessing it will be something like this:

```
x <- c(1,1,0,-1,0,1)
cumsum(x)


import numpy as np
print(np.cumsum([1,1,0,-1,0,1]))
```

I'm not sure how to add in the buy, sell, or hold conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
np.cumsum(np.array([1,1,0,-1,0,1]),axis=0)
```

or using an example for IBM:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from datetime import datetime
ibm = pdr.get_data_yahoo(symbols='IBM', start=datetime(2015, 1, 1), end=datetime(2017, 1, 1))['Adj Close']
a=np.cumsum(np.array(np.sign(np.diff(ibm))))
```

Comment: Thanks Martien Lubberink!